# How to implement tablemodel in java?

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I am new with JAVA. I have started using JTable. I could not understand how to use tablemodel with JTable. Objective is to understand the use of tablemodel.

Comment: You should read about the Model-View-Controller paradigm

Comment: I know the Model-View-Controller structure paradigm. But I could not understand the use of tablemodel. Can you please help me understand its uses and advantages.

Comment: See also [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's name suggests... the TableModel is a model for the table. The JTable is a generic utility which can display data from any source. By implementing a concrete TableModel you are giving the JTable all it needs to populate itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate using a simple example?

Comment: Can you please share a easy one? Like limitations that are solved by using tablemodel.

Comment: Without tablemodels, you wouldn't be able to set a model on a JTable. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29

Comment: What will happen if we do not set ant table model to the JTable?